# How to write data to existing Sharepoint 2007 Calender List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Domestic demand,We must let our develop system form  copy to the WSS 3.0 Calendar list
Simply put, I know need to use ADO to update [Alluserdata] this table and also know whitch
tp_listId.

However, after updating, has written to the database, it can not appear in Sharepoint page 
What am I do some thing wrong...
ps: suspected tp_size field related, but not sure ....

```
 Public Sub Pm_woToSharePoint(ByVal PM_WO_MAIN_VIEWRow As PM_WO_MAIN_VIEW)
     Try
         Dim cdataobj As New cDataACCESS
         Dim dt_Prolist As Data.DataTable
         Dim selectString As String


        selectString = "select top 1 * from AllUserData where   tp_listId='4C0516DB-B090-4740-A0F0-B99E6DC31C0C' order by tp_id desc"
         dt_Prolist = cdataobj.sqlDt(selectString, "SharepointConnectionString")
         Dim CalenderListRow As Data.DataRow = dt_Prolist.NewRow
         Dim CalenderListRow2 As Data.DataRow = dt_Prolist.Rows(0)
         With CalenderListRow2
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ID") = .Item("tp_id") + 1
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ListId") = .Item("tp_ListId")
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_SiteId") = .Item("tp_SiteId")
             ' CalenderListRow.Item("tp_RowOrdinal") = 0
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_Version") = 1
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_Author") = 96
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_Editor") = 96
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_Modified") = Now
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_Created") = Now
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_Ordering") = DBNull.Value
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ThreadIndex") = DBNull.Value
             ' CalenderListRow.Item("tp_HasAttachment") = 0
             'CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ModerationStatus") = 0
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_IsCurrent") = 1
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ItemOrder") = 100 * CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ID")
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_InstanceID") = DBNull.Value
             '  CalenderListRow.Item("tp_GUID") = 4
             ' CalenderListRow.Item("tp_CopySource") = DBNull.Value
             'CalenderListRow.Item("tp_HasCopyDestinations") = DBNull.Value
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_AuditFlags") = DBNull.Value
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_InheritAuditFlags") = DBNull.Value
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_Size") = .Item("tp_Size")
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_WorkflowVersion") = 1
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_WorkflowInstanceID") = DBNull.Value
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_DirName") = .Item("tp_DirName")
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_LeafName") = CStr(CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ID")) & "_.000"
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_DeleteTransactionId") = .Item("tp_DeleteTransactionId")
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ContentType") = .Item("tp_ContentType")
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_ContentTypeId") = .Item("tp_ContentTypeId")
             CalenderListRow.Item("nvarchar1") = PM_WO_MAIN_VIEWRow.ITEM_NAME & " " & PM_WO_MAIN_VIEWRow.ITEM_VALUE
             CalenderListRow.Item("nvarchar3") = PM_WO_MAIN_VIEWRow.ST_NAME_CHT
             CalenderListRow.Item("ntext2") = "機台:" & PM_WO_MAIN_VIEWRow.MS_NAME_CHT & " 生產人員:" & PM_WO_MAIN_VIEWRow.ProductPerson
             CalenderListRow.Item("datetime1") = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, -8, CType(PM_WO_MAIN_VIEWRow.START_TIME, DateTime))
             CalenderListRow.Item("datetime2") = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, -8, CType(PM_WO_MAIN_VIEWRow.END_TIME, DateTime))
             CalenderListRow.Item("int1") = 0
             '  CalenderListRow.Item("int2") = .Item("int2")
             CalenderListRow.Item("bit1") = 0
             CalenderListRow.Item("bit2") = 0
             CalenderListRow.Item("bit3") = 0
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_Level") = 1
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_IsCurrentVersion") = 1
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_UIVersion") = 512
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_CalculatedVersion") = 0
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_UIVersionString") = "1.0"
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_DraftOwnerId") = DBNull.Value
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_UIVersionString") = DBNull.Value
             CalenderListRow.Item("tp_CheckoutUserId") = DBNull.Value
         End With

        dt_Prolist.Rows.Add(CalenderListRow)
         cdataobj.ExecSQL(dt_Prolist, selectString, "SharepointConnectionString")
     Catch ex As System.Exception
         Throw
     End Try
 End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you access SharePoint database directly, instead of using SharePoint API?!? That's really **BAD** idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on totally the wrong track here accessing the database directly, its dangerous and [unsupported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861829%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

The correct way to do things like this is the object model or web services (or client object model in 2010) - see [here](http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/08/10/introducing-the-sharepoint-object-model/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473633%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to get started.

This is for 2010, but its identical steps 2007 - [How to add a event to a SharePoint 2010 Calendar](http://quicklookfordotnet.wordpress.com/2010/10/27/programmatically-add-an-itemevent-to-a-sharepoint-2010-calendar/)

```
SPListItem newEvent = yourCalendar.Items.Add();

newEvent["Location"] = "This is location";
newEvent["Start Time"] = DateTime.Now;
newEvent["End Time"] = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
newEvent["Description"] = "Going for Meting";
newEvent["Title"] = "New Meting";
newEvent["fAllDayEvent"]  =  false;
newEvent["Category"] = "Meting";

//Create Event in the sharpoint.         
newEvent.Update();
```

Comment: Thank's Ryan.Our develop NB OS is Windows 7 64 bit and I try to install WSS 3.0 64 Bit.But I can't install this,so I open iis and www service.Last....I can't find [WSS on Windows 7]...

Comment: You need to ask this as another question ("how to develop wss on win 7 x64") - thats how this website works. Whilst you're at it don't forget to mark this answer as correct if you feel its helped (click on tick mark) an dread FAQ top right.